# Elastic Beanstalk Auto Scaling - Which metric should I use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got an application that is built in node.js, and is primarily used to post photos to (up to 25mb).  The app resizes to thumbnail size, and moves both the thumbnail and full size image to S3.  When the uploads begin happening, they usually come in bursts of 10-15 pictures, rinse, wash, repeat in 5 minute durations.  I'm seeing a lot of scaling, and the trigger is the default 6MB NetworkOut trigger. My question is, is the moving the photos to S3 considered NetworkOut?  Or should I consider a different scaling trigger, so far the app hasn't stuttered so I'm hesitant to not fix what ain't broken, but I am seeing quite a big of scaling so I thought I would investigate.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer - scale when ever a resource is constrained. eg, If your instances can keep up with network IO or cpu is above 80% then scale.  Yes, sending any data from your ec2 instance is network out traffic.  You got to get that data from point A to B somehow :)

As you go up in size on ec2 instances you get more memory and cpu along with more network IO.   If you don't see issue with transfers you may want to switch the auto scale over to watch cpu or memory.  In an app I'm working on users can start jobs which require a bit of cpu.  So I have my auto-scale to scale if my cpu is over 80%.   But you might have a process that consumes a lot of memory and not much cpu...

On a side note - you may want to think about having your uploads go directly to your s3 bucket and use a lambda to trigger the resize routine.  This has several advantages over your current design. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Comment: Thanks denov, that's an interesting idea (going direct to s3).  I'll give that a look, and appreciate the info on proper scaling!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting familiar with the instance metrics. You can then recognize your app-specific bottlenecks on the current instance type and count.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-metrics.html